# sending javascript object with key : function pair in jade template

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

i am rendering a jade file as :

On server side :

```
var html = jade.renderFile('ui/index.jade', {
    printHello : function(){
       console.log('Hello World');
    }
});
```

On client side in `index.jade` :

```
script(type="text/javascript").
      var s = #{JSON.stringify(patternMatch)};
      s.printHello(); //Desired to print 'Hello world' on browser console
```

But `s.printHello()` says Object Object does not have function 'printHello';

and `console.log(s);` // gives {} 'empty object';

Why is that so.?

And how do i make `printHello` present and work?

Answer (score 0):

this is what i did. i send the stringed code from server

```
var html = jade.renderFile('ui/index.jade', {
    printHello : "("+"function(){ console.log('Hello World'); }"+")"
});
```

Then on client side

```
script(type="text/javascript").
      var s = !{JSON.stringify(patternMatch)};
      var myFunc = eval(s['printHello'])
      console.log(myFunc()); //prints "Hello World" on client browser
```